# Как скопировать шаблона с сайта на wordpress?

Tags: веб-дизайн, html

Есть сторонний сайт на движке wordperss. Как можно скопировать или вытащить дизайт с этого сайта?

Answer (score 2):

[@privetsh](/users/16138/privetsh), действовать по схеме:

1. Учите HTML и основы верстки
2. После или параллельно - изучаете css
3. Осваиваете какой-нибудь графический редактор

Думаю, что вы не только сможете скопировать тот сайт, а и создать дизайн получше. И тогда все остальные уже будут глотать слюнки от желания скомуниздить дизайн у вас.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - выяснить источник/автора их шаблона - возможно, он прописан в комментариях в CSS / JS / HTML страницы. И тогда можно купить/бесплатно скачать там же.